# Select date from combo and match with string and if do not select any date from combo then print current date

Tags: php

I have a big string like given below i retrive only date from string that are present after exploding string from | and ~ in 6th index.and show date in a combo box.now i compare whole string with select date from combo box and print matched date.here all is working fine,but now i want if user does not select any date means when first time page is open print first date matched whole string.means when user go this page first time he would not select anything then print very first date matched all string.

```
 2~FAFO/683/2014~27~HIMANSHU AND ANOTHER~SUDHANSHU AND 2 ORS.~D~2014-03-19~06:11:16 
 18/03/2014|9~COPP/43/2012~21~DASAPRAKASH HOTELS AND RESORTS PVT. LTD.~M/S KUMAR ASHIYANA 
 PVT.LTD.~D~2014-03-24~06:11:16 18/03/2014|10~WRIA/50923/2012~27~LALLAN KUMAR~COAL INDIA
 LTD. THRU. ITS CHAIRMAN AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-24~06:11:16
 18/03/2014|10~WRIA/52176/2011~49~MANEESH THAKUR~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-
 24~06:11:16 18/03/2014|39~WRIC/48169/2002~6~TAUFIQ KAMAL~STATE OF U.P. THRU  SECY.  
 HOUSING GOVT. OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-24~06:11:16 
 18/03/2014|39~WRIC/14267/2007~69~MUNNI 
 LAL BHARGAVA~STATE OF U.P. AND OTHERS~D~2014-03-24~06:11:16 19/03/2014


$selecteddate = $_GET[ "selecteddate" ];

             $causelistarray = explode('|',$return);
          $causelistlen= count($causelistarray);
            for( $a=0;$a<$causelistlen; $a++)
                    {

                    $final = explode ('~',$causelistarray[$a]);
                    $da=$final[6];
                        if( $final[6] == $selecteddate)
                            {
                             print"<ul data-role=listview  data-icon=false style=margin-top:15px;>";
                             print" <li >";

                             print"<font class=alignleft size='3' style=color:#FFFF00;>";
                                if($final[0] == '0')
                                  {
                                  echo  $final[0]= 'CJ';
                                  }
                                else
                                 {
                                   echo $final[0]; 
                                 }

                               print"</font>";
                               print"<font size='3' class=aligncenter style=color:#FF8000;>";

                                echo $final[2];
                                print"</font>";
                                print"<font class=alignright size='3' style=color:#00CC00;>";
                                echo $final[1]; 
                                print"</font>";
                                print"<br/>";
                                print"<br/>";
                                print"<font   style=margin-left:7%;color:#01DFD7;>";
                                echo "Party 1:-". $final[3];
                                print"</font>";
                                print"<br/>";

                               print"<font   style=margin-left:7%;color:#FFFFFF;>";
                               echo "Party 2:-". $final[4];
                               print"</font>";
                               print"</a>";
                               print" </li >";
                               print" </ul>";



                            }

                          //elseif($final[6] == $item[6])
                          elseif($selecteddate == 0)

                          {


                          print"<ul data-role=listview  data-icon=false style=margin-top:2%;>";
                             print" <li >";

                             print"<font class=alignleft size='3' style=color:#FFFF00;>";
                                if($final[0] == '0')
                                  {
                                  echo  $final[0]= 'CJ';
                                  }
                                else
                                 {
                                   echo $final[0]; 
                                 }

                               print"</font>";
                               print"<font size='3' class=aligncenter style=color:#FF8000;>";

                                echo $final[2];
                                print"</font>";
                                print"<font class=alignright size='3' style=color:#00CC00;>";
                                echo $final[1]; 
                                print"</font>";
                                print"<br/>";
                                print"<br/>";
                                print"<font   style=margin-left:7%;color:#01DFD7;>";
                                echo "Party 1:-". $final[3];
                                print"</font>";
                                print"<br/>";

                               print"<font   style=margin-left:7%;color:#FFFFFF;>";
                               echo "Party 2:-". $final[4];
                               print"</font>";
                               print"</a>";
                               print" </li >";
                               print" </ul>";




                          }


                    }
```

please help me as soon as possible.thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to understand question clearly but I am answering it from whatever I understood. If this was not what you want comment.

```
$causelistarray = explode('|',$return);
$causelistlen= count($causelistarray);
if(isset($_GET[ "selecteddate" ])){
  $selecteddate = $_GET[ "selecteddate" ];
}else{
   $selecteddate = explode ('~',$causelistarray[0])[6];//get very first date of data
 for( $a=1;$a<$causelistlen; $a++){
 $tmp=explode ('~',$causelistarray[$a])[6];
 if($tmp<$selecteddate)
 $selecteddate=$tmp;
 }
}
for( $a=0;$a<$causelistlen; $a++)
                ........to be continued.........
```

Comment: sir i want print  date wise data means user select date matched with  whole string date and print data of matched date.i have done this task but now i am trying when user not select any date means he open page first time then show only very first date data,like date is 19/03/2014,21/03/2014,24/03/2014....,then print only 19/03/2014 data only.and if he select any date print only matched data from string